# AWS Certificate Manager for ELB pointing to a Apache Server Running on EC2

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

I was reading the aws documentation for Certificate Manager. I can associate a SSL certificate for a ELB. I have already done that and my application is still residing on Apache server deployed on a Ubuntu EC2 server.

[image]

And in the documentation it has the following,

> Note Currently, ACM Certificates are associated with Elastic Load
>   Balancing load balancers or Amazon CloudFront distributions. Although
>   you install your website on an Amazon EC2 instance, you do not deploy
>   an ACM Certificate there. Instead, deploy the ACM Certificate on your
>   Elastic Load Balancing load balancer or on your CloudFront
>   distribution.

To my understanding, that means we can just deploy the application on a EC2 and add it under a load balance that has certificate from the ACM.

And that is all you need to have to work SSL for your web application.

But when I am not using this approach, I was using the following Apache configuration to configure SSL.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias example.com
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/diyoron-error_log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/diyoron-access_log common


        <Directory /var/www/html/>
                RewriteEngine on
                RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
                RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R]
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        # ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/

        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias example.com
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example-error_log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example-access_log common
        SSLEngine On

        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem

</VirtualHost>
```

But In my current arrangement I can not configure SSLCertificateKeyFile, SSLCertificateChainFile , SSLCertificateFile in my Apache configuration.

If anybody can direct me to a right path that is much appreciated.

```
AH00016: Configuration Failed
[Fri Apr 21 23:14:01.184314 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 1190] AH02572: Failed to configure at least one certificate and key for example.com:443
[Fri Apr 21 23:14:01.184826 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 1190] SSL Library Error: error:140A80B1:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_check_private_key:no certificate assigned
[Fri Apr 21 23:14:01.184834 2017] [ssl:emerg] [pid 1190] AH02311: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting. See /var/log/apache2/error.log for more information
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will terminate SSL on youe ELB and configure it to forward both HTTP and HTTPS requests as HTTP (to your instance's port 80):

[image]

Therefore, you will not need `<VirtualHost *:443>` anymore.

Also, in your Apache configuration, in `<VirtualHost *:80>` you are redirecting users to `https://` if the connection is not using SSL/TLS (btw, that condition was unnecessary, request would have never reached that point if it was using https - you could just unconditionally redirect it). This will not be possible any more since, from apache's point of view, all incoming connections use `http://`.

To determine the protocol used between the client and the load balancer, use the `X-Forwarded-Proto` request header (Elastic Load Balancing stores the protocol used between the client and the load balancer in the `X-Forwarded-Proto` request header and passes the header along to your server):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I think this is a classic ELB. Your approach has taken me further. Thank you.